# outputting HTML5 canvas as an image, howto?

Tags: javascript, html

I have already looked into this tutorial on how to use canvas in HTML5 to create a clipping mask.
http://www.benbarnett.net/2011/06/02/using-html5-canvas-for-image-masks/

The question i have now is it possible to save the canvas as an image (including the mask effect) ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Comment: Do you want to save the image on the server or the client?

Comment: Basically i want to save it on the server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting PNG output can be done with `canvas.toDataURL()`.

It is also possible to get JPEG output on Chrome/Firefox. Below is a code to convert  to JPEG data as HTML5 Blob.

```
   /**
    * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158
    *
    *
    */
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI, callback) {
        // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
        // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs

        var byteString;
        if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        } else {
            byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        }

        // separate out the mime component
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

        // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
        var BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
        var bb = new BlobBuilder();
        bb.append(ab);
        return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
    }

   function getAsJPEGBlob(canvas) {
        if(canvas.mozGetAsFile) {
            return canvas.mozGetAsFile("foo.jpg", "image/jpeg");
        } else {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
            var blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
            return blob;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Further source can be found here https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/tools/resizer.js#L51

Comment: You can add ` || window.MSBlobBuilder` to support IE too.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```

is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Example%3a_Getting_the_data%3a_URL_for_a_canvas) to get you a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) which you can put into an image tag. From there you can save it.

If you're looking to *automatically* save it to the harddrive, that isn't possible in standard JavaScript

Comment: Not yet anyways, it does look like we will start to see file writing APIs in browsers eventually.

Comment: @MattGreer: That seems like a pretty bad idea, security-wise.

Comment: @You Thankfully I'm not the one making those decisions :)

Comment: luckily i only need to save it on the server