# Using Javascript is there a way to grab the background image rendered by a linear or radial gradient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background-image, gradient

I'm specifically interested in gradients but I suppose the question applies to images rendered with any method, such as data:image/svg+xml;...

Is it possible?

ETA:

This was possible by rendering the gradient onto a canvas. For anyone interested in saving a .png of a CSS3 linear or radial gradient, go to:

http://www.visualcsstools.com/gradient-generator.htm

Design your gradient, click the CVS (canvas) button and right-click the gradient preview to save it as an image.

Comment: Some type of situation and an example of what you're really trying to do will limit the broad answers your bound to get. Try to be more specific!

Comment: If you go to http://www.visualcsstools.com/, you'll see a web app that generates radial and linear gradients for any parameters, not just simple up/down, left/right linear gradients. I was looking for a fall back where CSS and SVG is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DOM element with a CSS gradient background, no way to do that without a screen shot utility.

However, if you drew a gradient in a canvas element (and any other graphics in the canvas element), you could export the graphic of the canvas element as a JPG or PNG using JavaScript in the browser. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780628/outputting-html5-canvas-as-an-image-howto).

Comment: It looks like the way to go. I've managed to do CSS Linear to Canvas Linear (pretty much the same as CSS to SVG), now hopefully radial is just as easy!

Answer (score -3):

By taking a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with javascript, as specified in the question?